# Connect to SharePoint online in .net core

Tags: sharepoint, .net-core

Recently my application was converted from `.net framework 4.6` application to `.net core 2.0` app.

In the application I used `SharePointOnlineCredentials` to connect SharePoint. This class (which you can find in `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll`) doesn't support .net core yet.

I did try to use `NetworkCredential` class but it doesn't seem to work (Username like `xx@company.onmicrosoft.com`).

I would like to avoid working with `OAuth` if possible.
Any idea?
Thanks!